# How do I add Google's MLKit Vision Text Recognition to a static framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-mlkit

I have a static framework in iOS. This framework has to do some OCR on an image.
Fo which I need to add Google's MLKit Vision Text Recognition (on-device) to this static framework.
<del>I can't add from cocoapods.</del>
**Edit:** Adding cocoapods will make the framework dynamic and I need to keep the framework static. So, I can't add from cocoapods to the framework.
Is there any way to add Google's MLKit Vision Text Recognition without cocoapods?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out ML Kit [quickstart vision sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios/quickstarts/vision)?  It shows you how to add ML Kit text recognition from the cocoapods.

Comment: Yes, sample app does show how to add from cocoapods.
But I can not add from cocoapods because I need to add to the static framework.

Adding cocoapods to framework makes it dynamic and I am not supposed to do it as other things are dependent on being the framework as static.

Comment: I'm not an expert on cocoapods, so not sure why adding cocoapods to a framework makes it dynamic, but have you tried linking the cocoapod statically by replacing `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile with `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static` to see if that solves your problem? I tried that in ML Kit's sample app and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @madhurtewani friendly ping